# why CLR doesn't compile overflow const and but for variables it does?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

See the code below, I just want to understand the reason behind that...

```
const int a = 2147483647;
const int b = 2147483647;

int c = a + b; // it doesn't allow to compile!!! 

int a = 2147483647;
int b = 2147483647;

int c = a + b; // it allows to compile!!!
```

Comment: Just a guess, but surely because they are constants, and the compiler can see for definite that when added they *will* overflow, whereas with a variable it treats the values as unknown.

Comment: Side note: CLR does not compile C# source code, it is C# compiler's work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`const` expressions are resolved at compile-time, non-`const` expressions are resolved at runtime. Each have different types of overflow checking contexts by default. According to the C# specification:

> For non-constant expressions (expressions that are evaluated at
>   run-time) that are not enclosed by any checked or unchecked operators
>   or statements, **the default overflow checking context is unchecked**
>   unless external factors (such as compiler switches and execution
>   environment configuration) call for checked evaluation.

Which is why you're not seeing a runtime error when you use local variables to do the arithmetic. As for the `const` calculation:

> For constant expressions (expressions that can be fully evaluated at
>   compile-time), **the default overflow checking context is always
>   checked**. Unless a constant expression is explicitly placed in an
>   unchecked context, overflows that occur during the compile-time
>   evaluation of the expression always cause compile-time errors.

Which is why you're seeing a compile-time error with your `const` calculation.

[More information about checked and unchecked on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khy08726%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

For constant values, the compiler essentially replaces the variable with the constant value at compile time. Therefore, when the addition statement is evaluated at compile time, it is able to know the values and see the overflow condition.

For the integer type variables, I don't think the compiler actually takes the assigned values into account at compile time, but rather evaluates the expression at runtime.

But C#, turns out that check is disabled by default. You can turn it on in the options. See Justin Etheredge's excellent blog post on the whys and how's:

http://www.codethinked.com/c-trivia-what-no-overflow

Comment: but even in the runtime it doesn't throw exception for the overflow condition

Answer (score 0):

I assume its because the compliler knows that the `const` can't be modified so `a+b` will fail.
But with other variables they can be changed in runtime so the compliler will not assume the values set will not change to a valid value.